# AppFabric deep copy into cache

Tags: appfabric

I'm using Windows Server AppFabric 1.0.4632 and when I put an object into the cache and get it back, it has nulls in place of the complex properties. How do I force a deep copy of some properties? (Preferably at class level (Attribute)).

Comment: Can you show a simple example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thanks. I figured out what the problem was. The class was ISerializable and therefore had custom rules for the serialization that were not matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppFabric uses internally the `NetDataContractSerializer`, you can use the following guide for the deep copy: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Deep-Copy-NetDataContractSe-c57abdc0